# What upgrades transfer from Mass Effect 2?

Tags: mass-effect-2, mass-effect-3

Is there any benefit into maxing your Weapon, Biotic, or Tech upgrades in a Mass Effect 2 save before importing to Mass Effect 3?

Credits are at a premium in Mass Effect 2, and if there's no benefit to spending them, I'd rather spend them on Space Hamsters.

Comment: Space hamsters *are* a good investment

Comment: I'm going to be sad if those 3 million resources I mined in ME2 don't have some benefit in ME3. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appears to be no benefit. While your character's *level* and skill selection transfers over, I don't seem to have retained any of my equipment or upgrades.

Normandy upgrades are retained, but those have other impacts across transferred saves as well (Suicide mission survival), so it's unlikely that you won't bring those over unless you actively avoided them.

Comment: Normandy Upgrades (Shields, Armor, Thanix Cannon) seem to have passed over, but otherwise, I think you're right.

Comment: @Raven, do they affect gameplay or is it just aesthetic?

Comment: @JuanManuel They seem to be worth a few points towards the Galaxy at War counter. Which is a gameplay effect, but it's a pretty damned minimal one.

Answer (score 0):

If you have upgrades in ME2, the only thing you get in ME3 is your character 1st upgrades points, this happens when you import your character you get to have a little upgrade at the beginning in Mars mission which is better than having a low rate weapon.